# nginx url rewrite for angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I am building a website based on angularjs and nginx server.I am struggling at url rewrite for angularjs , I used my development environment as apache which is working well.I want to use extensionless php so that if i visit www.mywebsite.com/register it points to www.mywebsite.com/register.php . When I put slash near www.mywebsite.com/register/it is not working.For angular I want the url as www.mywebsite.com/register/step2 to www.mywebsite.com/register/#!/step2

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost www.mywebsite.com;

    #charset koi8-r;
   #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/india.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/mywebsite;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }
location ~ /register/ {
    rewrite ^ register.php/#/$1 redirect;
    break;
  }
    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/mywebsite;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 location /api/ {
     try_files $uri $uri /api/index.php?$query_string;
    }
 location ~ \.php$ {
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^?]*)\.php($|\?)) {  return 302 /$1?$args;  }
        root           html;
        #include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mywebsite$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 404 /404;
    }
        location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

# if enable status in PHP-FPM config
location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
 allow 127.0.0.1;
 #deny all;
 include fastcgi_params;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
}
```